# How to get typed array elements by name?

Tags: typescript

I have a super-long API response that goes like `....[[[[1,2,3,4],"something"],"etc"`, and instead of getting this values like `response[0][3][6][1]` I'd like to introduce types to call it like `response.cars[1].color`.

So I've introduced a type like this `type Car = [color: string, hp: number];`. Now I can define variables like `const a : Car = ["red", 100]` and TS checks the types like you'd expect.

However I can't see how I can make use of the aliases I've defined (color, number) to access the values I'm interested in. Is there any syntax to write stuff like `a.color` and have it return `red`?

Comment: Tuples are arrays at runtime, the name annotations for them are just for documentation, at runtime you stll need to index by number. You can switch to using an object instead

Comment: Alternatively: `const color = 0; console.log(a[color])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. In the end I went with the `enum` solution:

```
enum CarResponse {
    Make,
    Model,
    HP,
    Type
}
```

and I use it like `apiResponse[CarResponse.Type]`